# What other ways can I go about finding the solution to this limit: $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{9^x - 4^x}{2^x - 3^x}$

Tags: limits

I'm searching for another way to solve 
$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{9^x - 4^x}{2^x - 3^x}$.

I used L'Hospital's rule making it $\frac{\ln9(9^x) - \ln4(4^x)}{\ln2(2^x) - \ln3(3^x)}$

This gave me an answer of -2. I'm searching for another way I can do this problem. I tried multiplying by the conjugate of both the top and bottom but it always becomes 0. Does anyone have any suggestions on another way I can do this? Am I missing something fundamental and obvious about limits?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{9^x-4^x}{2^x-3^x}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(3^x-2^x)(3^x+2^x)}{2^x-3^x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-(2^x-3^x)(3^x+2^x)}{2^x-3^x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0} -(3^x+2^x)\\
&=-2\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Does it depend on the specific choice of the numbers? What if one replaces 9 with, say, 10?

Comment: 10 stills has a square root. It just isn't an integer (or even rational).

Comment: ...But of course, for the cancellation to work you would need to also change the 3 in the denominator to sqrt(10).

Comment: @Vim Nilknarf has noticed that the numerator can be factored out into terms that include the denominator. This allows cancelling the denominator. If the numerator had different values, it might not be possible to factor into terms that include the denominator. If not, then the cancellation can't be performed, and you'll need a different approach.